# how to 'inject' confirm event into react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using this project https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select for select component. I use it to render a multi select component. Below is a sample code:

```
import Async from 'react-select/lib/Async';

<Async
                    className="user-select"
                    classNamePrefix="user-select"
                    defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue}
                    defaultOptions
                    isClearable={false}
                    loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
                    isMulti
                />
```

below is a screenshot. It renders two items `Purple` and `Red`.

[image]

The item will be removed when I click the close button after each item. How can I add a prompt model to ask user confirm before deleting?

Comment: Looks like you are most experienced SO community user. Please may I request you to share the minimum and relevant code related to the problem?

Comment: sorry for confusing. I have updated my question

Comment: I have added as an answer

Answer (score 2):

on clicking the item send that particular id to the event handler function and set that value and id in the state and also do setState for modal to true to show the model when item is clicked

You also make sure to set the showModal to false when user clicks yes or no in the modal so that it will work next time when you want to delete other item.

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        itemId: 0,
        showModal: false,
        itemValue: ""
     }
   }

   handleItem = event => {
      this.setState({
         itemId: event.target.id,
         showModal: true,
         itemValue: event.target.value
      });
   }

   resetModalFlag = () => {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false
        })
   }

   render(){
      const { showModal, itemId, itemValue } = this.state;
      return(
          <div>
             <Select onChange={this.handleItem} />
             {showModal && <Modal id={itemId} itemValue={itemValue}  resetModalFlag={this.resetModalFlag} />}
          </div>
      )
   }
```

In Modal component access `itemId` and `itemValue` using this.props and you can show text like are you sure you want delete `this.props.itemValue` With yes or no button. When either one of these buttons clicked you need to call resetModalFlag in yes and no button event handler functions like

```
  handleYesButton= () =>{
       this.props.resetModalFlag();
  }

  handleNoButton= () =>{
       this.props.resetModalFlag();
  }
```

Comment: how it is related to `react-select`? do you really think it's a only handling modal confirm problem?

Comment: I gave him hint about how to show modal when the button is clicked and how to handle it in general. I didn’t talk specific about react-select because OP doesn’t provide React-select code uses in the component. But any way I have added for React-select in my answer based on docs

Comment: it's still not multi select related - not deleting 'Red' or 'Purple' values separately

Comment: @xadm please share the complete code you tried and not working I can help on that

Comment: I don't need this ;) (I would probably deal with it myself) - I wrote your answer don't answer the main question, it's only partially related. ... we must wait till tommorow (?) for the author ;)

Comment: My answer is for @Zhao Yi not for you:) moreover who are you to tell me that you don’t need this

Comment: I know how to show the modal but I don't know how to attach the listener. If I use `onChange` method, the item is already removed from the select component.